# What does nouveau's "func 08 lookup failed, -2" mean?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, nvidia, graphics, dmesg

## Arch Linux Question

I have an Nvidia 9500 GT

- Chipset: G96 (NV96)
- Family : [NV50](http://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/CodeNames/)

This means I can use proprietary pack `nvidia-340xx` + `nvidia-340xx-libgl`, but I opted for the [open source option](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nouveau):  `xf86-video-nouveau` + `mesa-libgl`

I have spent hours trying to get the X server running.

UPDATE: X Server is running find. I am still getting this nebulous error. I would like to identify the cause.

## xrandr

```
[root@**** ~]# xrandr
Can't open display
```

## dmesg | grep nouveau

### func 08 lookup failed, -2

```
[root@**** ~]# dmesg | grep nouveau
[    0.432008] fb: switching to nouveaufb from VESA VGA
[    0.432699] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] BOOT0  : 0x096000c1
[    0.432702] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] Chipset: G96 (NV96)
[    0.432704] nouveau  [  DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] Family : NV50
[    0.547623] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] using image from PRAMIN
[    0.547724] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] BIT signature found
[    0.547727] nouveau  [   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] version 62.94.73.00.00
[    0.568050] nouveau  [     PMC][0000:01:00.0] MSI interrupts enabled
[    0.568070] nouveau W[   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] M0203T not found
[    0.568071] nouveau W[   VBIOS][0000:01:00.0] M0203E not matched!
[    0.568078] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:01:00.0] RAM type: DDR2
[    0.568080] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:01:00.0] RAM size: 1024 MiB
[    0.568081] nouveau  [     PFB][0000:01:00.0]    ZCOMP: 2048 tags
[    0.596815] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:01:00.0] FAN control: none / external
[    0.596824] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:01:00.0] fan management: automatic
[    0.596829] nouveau  [  PTHERM][0000:01:00.0] internal sensor: yes
[    0.616840] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:01:00.0] 0f: core 550 MHz shader 1350 MHz memory 400 MHz
[    0.616871] nouveau  [     CLK][0000:01:00.0] --: core 400 MHz shader 800 MHz memory 399 MHz
[    0.616919] nouveau E[   PDISP][0000:01:00.0][0x00000000] 01:0130: func 08 lookup failed, -2
[    0.617043] nouveau  [     DRM] VRAM: 1024 MiB
[    0.617044] nouveau  [     DRM] GART: 1048576 MiB
[    0.617047] nouveau  [     DRM] TMDS table version 2.0
[    0.617048] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB version 4.0
[    0.617050] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 00: 02000300 00000028
[    0.617052] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 01: 01000302 00020030
[    0.617054] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 02: 04011310 00000028
[    0.617055] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 03: 02011312 00c200b0
[    0.617057] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB outp 04: 010223f1 00c0c080
[    0.617059] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 00: 00001030
[    0.617061] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 01: 00002130
[    0.617062] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 02: 00000210
[    0.617064] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 03: 00000211
[    0.617065] nouveau  [     DRM] DCB conn 04: 00000213
[    0.624739] nouveau W[     DRM] failed to create encoder 0/1/0: -19
[    0.624741] nouveau W[     DRM] TV-1 has no encoders, removing
[    0.632829] nouveau  [     DRM] MM: using CRYPT for buffer copies
[    0.710667] nouveau  [     DRM] allocated 1920x1080 fb: 0x70000, bo ffff8800374c8000
[    0.710736] fbcon: nouveaufb (fb0) is primary device
[    0.779679] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fb0: nouveaufb frame buffer device
[    0.779680] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: registered panic notifier
[    0.810014] [drm] Initialized nouveau 1.2.2 20120801 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
```

## vim /var/log/Xorg.0.log (with line numbers "show nu" on)

```
 1 [  5393.652]
  2 X.Org X Server 1.17.2
  3 Release Date: 2015-06-16
  4 [  5393.653] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
  5 [  5393.654] Build Operating System: Linux 4.0.4-2-ARCH x86_64
  6 [  5393.654] Current Operating System: Linux bigbeef 4.1.3-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 22     20:37:12 CEST 2015 x86_64
  7 [  5393.654] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=8c163fb0-3cc8-44a9-bc    99-f95d29c1fbb4 rw quiet
  8 [  5393.655] Build Date: 17 July 2015  05:38:19PM
  9 [  5393.655]
 10 [  5393.656] Current version of pixman: 0.32.6
 11 [  5393.657]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
 12         to make sure that you have the latest version.
 13 [  5393.657] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
 14         (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
 15         (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
 16 [  5393.658] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat Aug  1 12:50:33 2015
 17 [  5393.659] (II) Loader magic: 0x817d60
 18 [  5393.659] (II) Module ABI versions:
 19 [  5393.659]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
 20 [  5393.659]    X.Org Video Driver: 19.0
 21 [  5393.659]    X.Org XInput driver : 21.1
 22 [  5393.659]    X.Org Server Extension : 9.0
 23 [  5393.660] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/c    1
 24 [  5393.661] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
 25 [  5393.661] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 8 paused 0
 26 [  5393.663] (--) PCI:*(0:1:0:0) 10de:0640:3842:c959 rev 161, Mem @ 0xfa000000/16777216, 0x    e0000000/268435456, 0xf8000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x0000ef00/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
 27 [  5393.663] List of video drivers:
 28 [  5393.663]    siliconmotion
 29 [  5393.663]    sis
 30 [  5393.663]    nouveau
 31 [  5393.663]    radeon
 32 [  5393.663]    tdfx
 33 [  5393.663]    voodoo
 34 [  5393.663]    savage
 35 [  5393.663]    ark
 36 [  5393.663]    openchrome
 37 [  5393.664]    nv
 38 [  5393.664]    neomagic
 39 [  5393.664]    i128
 40 [  5393.664]    mach64
 41 [  5393.664]    vmware
 42 [  5393.664]    glint
 43 [  5393.664]    r128
 44 [  5393.664]    ati
 45 [  5393.664]    dummy
 46 [  5393.664]    intel
 47 [  5393.664]    trident
 48 [  5393.664]    vesa
 49 [  5393.664]    fbdev
 50 [  5393.664]    modesetting
 51 [  5393.664] (II) LoadModule: "siliconmotion"
 52 [  5393.664] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/siliconmotion_drv.so
 53 [  5393.664] (II) Module siliconmotion: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 54 [  5393.664]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.7.8
 55 [  5393.664]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 56 [  5393.664]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
 57 [  5393.664] (II) LoadModule: "sis"
 58 [  5393.664] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/sis_drv.so
 59 [  5393.664] (II) Module sis: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 60 [  5393.664]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 0.10.7
 61 [  5393.664]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 62 [  5393.664]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
 63 [  5393.664] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
 64 [  5393.664] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
 65 [  5393.665] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 66 [  5393.665]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 1.0.11
 67 [  5393.665]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 68 [  5393.665]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
 69 [  5393.665] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
 70 [  5393.665] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
 71 [  5393.665] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 72 [  5393.665]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 7.5.0
 73 [  5393.665]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 74 [  5393.665]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
 75 [  5393.665] (II) LoadModule: "tdfx"
 76 [  5393.665] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/tdfx_drv.so
 77 [  5393.665] (II) Module tdfx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 78 [  5393.665]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 1.4.5
 79 [  5393.665]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 80 [  5393.665]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
 81 [  5393.665] (II) LoadModule: "voodoo"
 82 [  5393.665] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/voodoo_drv.so
 83 [  5393.665] (II) Module voodoo: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 84 [  5393.665]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 1.1.0
 85 [  5393.665]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 86 [  5393.665]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
 87 [  5393.665] (II) LoadModule: "savage"
 88 [  5393.665] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/savage_drv.so
 89 [  5393.665] (II) Module savage: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 90 [  5393.665]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 2.3.8
 91 [  5393.665]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 92 [  5393.666]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
 93 [  5393.666] (II) LoadModule: "ark"
 94 [  5393.666] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ark_drv.so
 95 [  5393.666] (II) Module ark: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 96 [  5393.666]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 0.7.5
 97 [  5393.666]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 98 [  5393.666]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
 99 [  5393.666] (II) LoadModule: "openchrome"
100 [  5393.666] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/openchrome_drv.so
101 [  5393.666] (II) Module openchrome: vendor="http://openchrome.org/"
102 [  5393.666]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 0.3.3
103 [  5393.666]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
104 [  5393.666]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
105 [  5393.666] (II) LoadModule: "nv"
106 [  5393.666] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nv_drv.so
107 [  5393.666] (II) Module nv: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
108 [  5393.666]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 2.1.20
109 [  5393.666]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
110 [  5393.666]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
111 [  5393.666] (II) LoadModule: "neomagic"
112 [  5393.666] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/neomagic_drv.so
113 [  5393.666] (II) Module neomagic: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
114 [  5393.666]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.2.9
115 [  5393.666]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
116 [  5393.667]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
117 [  5393.667] (II) LoadModule: "i128"
118 [  5393.667] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/i128_drv.so
119 [  5393.667] (II) Module i128: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
120 [  5393.667]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 1.3.6
121 [  5393.667]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
122 [  5393.667]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
123 [  5393.667] (II) LoadModule: "mach64"
124 [  5393.667] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/mach64_drv.so
125 [  5393.667] (II) Module mach64: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
126 [  5393.667]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 6.9.5
127 [  5393.667]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
128 [  5393.667]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
129 [  5393.667] (II) LoadModule: "vmware"
130 [  5393.667] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so
131 [  5393.685] (II) Module vmware: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
132 [  5393.685]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 13.1.0
133 [  5393.685]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
134 [  5393.685]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
135 [  5393.685] (II) LoadModule: "glint"
136 [  5393.685] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/glint_drv.so
137 [  5393.685] (II) Module glint: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
138 [  5393.686]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 1.2.8
139 [  5393.686]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
140 [  5393.686]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
141 [  5393.686] (II) LoadModule: "r128"
142 [  5393.686] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/r128_drv.so
143 [  5393.686] (II) Module r128: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
144 [  5393.686]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 6.10.0
145 [  5393.686]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
146 [  5393.686]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
147 [  5393.686] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
148 [  5393.686] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
149 [  5393.686] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
150 [  5393.686]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 7.5.0
151 [  5393.686]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
152 [  5393.686]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
153 [  5393.686] (II) LoadModule: "dummy"
154 [  5393.686] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/dummy_drv.so
155 [  5393.686] (II) Module dummy: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
156 [  5393.686]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 0.3.7
157 [  5393.686]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
158 [  5393.686]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
159 [  5393.667]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 1.3.6
160 [  5393.667]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
161 [  5393.667]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
162 [  5393.667] (II) LoadModule: "mach64"
163 [  5393.667] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/mach64_drv.so
164 [  5393.667] (II) Module mach64: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
165 [  5393.667]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 6.9.5
166 [  5393.667]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
167 [  5393.667]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
168 [  5393.667] (II) LoadModule: "vmware"
169 [  5393.667] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so
170 [  5393.685] (II) Module vmware: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
171 [  5393.685]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 13.1.0
172 [  5393.685]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
173 [  5393.685]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
174 [  5393.685] (II) LoadModule: "glint"
175 [  5393.685] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/glint_drv.so
176 [  5393.685] (II) Module glint: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
177 [  5393.686]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 1.2.8
178 [  5393.686]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
179 [  5393.686]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
180 [  5393.686] (II) LoadModule: "r128"
181 [  5393.686] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/r128_drv.so
182 [  5393.686] (II) Module r128: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
183 [  5393.686]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 6.10.0
184 [  5393.686]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
185 [  5393.686]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
186 [  5393.686] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
187 [  5393.686] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
188 [  5393.686] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
189 [  5393.686]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 7.5.0
190 [  5393.686]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
191 [  5393.686]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
192 [  5393.686] (II) LoadModule: "dummy"
193 [  5393.686] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/dummy_drv.so
194 [  5393.686] (II) Module dummy: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
195 [  5393.686]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 0.3.7
196 [  5393.686]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
197 [  5393.686]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
198 [  5393.686] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
199 [  5393.686] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
200 [  5393.687] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
201 [  5393.687]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 2.99.917
202 [  5393.687]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
203 [  5393.687]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
204 [  5393.687] (II) LoadModule: "trident"
205 [  5393.687] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/trident_drv.so
206 [  5393.687] (II) Module trident: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
207 [  5393.687]    compiled for 1.17.1, module version = 1.3.7
208 [  5393.687]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
209 [  5393.687]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
210 [  5393.687] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
211 [  5393.687] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
212 [  5393.687] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
213 [  5393.687]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 2.3.4
214 [  5393.687]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
215 [  5393.687]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
216 [  5393.687] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
217 [  5393.687] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
218 [  5393.687] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
219 [  5393.687]    compiled for 1.17.0, module version = 0.4.4
220 [  5393.687]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
221 [  5393.687]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
222 [  5393.687] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
223 [  5393.688] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
224 [  5393.688] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
225 [  5393.688]    compiled for 1.17.2, module version = 1.17.2
226 [  5393.688]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
227 [  5393.688]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 19.0
228 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for siliconmotion
229 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for sis
230 [  5393.688] (II) [drm] nouveau interface version: 1.2.2
231 [  5393.688] (II) NOUVEAU driver
232 [  5393.688] (II) NOUVEAU driver for NVIDIA chipset families :
233 [  5393.688]    RIVA TNT        (NV04)
234 [  5393.688]    RIVA TNT2       (NV05)
235 [  5393.688]    GeForce 256     (NV10)
236 [  5393.688]    GeForce 2       (NV11, NV15)
237 [  5393.688]    GeForce 4MX     (NV17, NV18)
238 [  5393.688]    GeForce 3       (NV20)
239 [  5393.688]    GeForce 4Ti     (NV25, NV28)
240 [  5393.688]    GeForce FX      (NV3x)
241 [  5393.688]    GeForce 6       (NV4x)
242 [  5393.688]    GeForce 7       (G7x)
243 [  5393.688]    GeForce 8       (G8x)
244 [  5393.688]    GeForce GTX 200 (NVA0)
245 [  5393.688]    GeForce GTX 400 (NVC0)
246 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for voodoo
247 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for ark
248 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for neomagic
249 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for i128
250 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for glint
251 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for dummy
252 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for trident
253 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa
254 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
255 [  5393.688] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
256 [  5393.688] No devices to configure.  Configuration failed.
```

Comment: According to lines 231 - 245, I don't see an entry for `NV50`  Are you sure your card is supported by this driver?

Comment: @eyoung100 I know, I saw that, but there is another source (see edit) that says otherwise. Actually, that is not the problem. I did a fresh install and everything is working fine. I just want to know what that error is, because I am still getting that error on my machine with the fully-functional graphics.

Comment: @yaoung100 You can also see from the `dmesg | grep nouveau` that the driver correctly identifies the card.

Comment: You could also try `#nouveau` on _irc.freenode.net_...

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks but as I said in the comment to eyoung100 above, I have a working system that runs to my satisfaction. I would just like to know what this error message means. Where is this documented? Why is it not easy to find?

Comment: Because this is a debug message and as such it's hard to know what it means (I don't know if it's even documented) hence my suggestion to try on #nouveau irc channel. They definitely know.

Comment: Seems like the kernel drm driver is looking for a gpio but can't find it [drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/engine/disp/conn.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/gpu/drm/nouveau/nvkm/engine/disp/conn.c#L124)

Comment: macmadness86 I'm sorry but I think @eyoung100 is right, the kernel drm driver and the xorg driver seems to not support your video card, nouveaufb does but I think is another driver just for the console (fbdev?)