# What would cause my video driver to stop working after every update?

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, video, graphics

I am not sure if this is a systemd issue (like order of loading modules) or a video driver issue. It does seem like every time

- I update boot-related stuff from a chrooted environment using my Arch ISO USB Stick, everything works.
- It is when I update from a running native system that things go sour AND I think when boot-related things are in that update.

## UPDATE 2016-04-18

I changed root (`arch-chroot`) into the machine and tried to rebuild the kernel with `mkinitcpio -p linux`. I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR: '/lib/modules/4.4.5-1-ARCH' is not a valid kernel module directory
> ```

## `uname -r` (check kernel version) yields

4.3.3-2-ARCH

## The folders in `/lib/modules/`

```
4.5.0-1-ARCH
extramodules-4.5-ARCH
```

Obviously when the kernel version numbers do not match the module version numbers, this is not good. Why would this happen? This would mean there is a problem with the way the system updates itself (pacman). Or did I do something wrong?

## `pacman -Qo /lib/modules/4.5.0-1-ARCH` (check package owner) yields

```
/usr/lib/modules/4.5.0-1-ARCH/ is owned by linux 4.5-1
/usr/lib/modules/4.5.0-1-ARCH/ is owned by linux-headers 4.5-1
```

If you give me suggestions in the comments, I'll try to be prompt at adding information.

## When Problem Happens

After running `yaourt -Syau --noconfirm` and rebooting, upon next boot my screen resolution gets messed up (appears the driver is working) and USB devices (keyboard+mouse) become nonresponsive. Could this be due to Grub?

Error after grub boot screen is

- Failure to Load Kernel Modules

## Machine Information

1. Bootloader is Grub 2
2. OS Arch Linux
3. Graphics GeForce 9500 GT (rev a1) with driver nouveau (acquired using `lspci -v | grep VGA -A 10`)

I can chroot into this machine by booting from an Arch ISO USB stick. Maybe it is helpful to know that I have recovered the system by waiting a few days for another update and then updating the system from a chrooted environment. Suddenly, everything starts working again. This has happened three times already. It just happened today and it is getting irritating.

[image]
[image]

## Possibly Related Questions

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224468/x-stopped-working-after-a-kernel-update
- [What does nouveau's "func 08 lookup failed, -2" mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219616/what-does-nouveaus-func-08-lookup-failed-2-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to note immediately that it is not just the video that has been disrupted. The modules/drivers were not permitted to load because of version-matching restraints.

## Update

This can be caused by having an error in /etc/fstab in the /boot mount for those who keep boot on a separate partition (usually EFI main boards). If during an update this partition is not mounted, the modules could (likely would) get upgraded while the kernel, which resides in /boot, would not. `dkms` normally prevents kernel-module mismatches.

---

I did indeed have kernel + module mismatch that led to the error message

> ERROR: '/lib/modules/4.4.5-1-ARCH' is not a valid kernel module directory

mentioned in the question.

To fix it, I needed to boot from an Arch USB Stick and mount the OS and BOOT partitions to /mnt and /mnt/boot, respectively. I had to change root over to the machine `arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash`and update my kernel manually (and forcefully).

```
pacman -Sy linux --force
```

This brought my system's kernel up to date with the modules (4.4.5-1-ARCH) such that they match (as they absolutely should!)

As to why there was a kernel + module mismatch, I don't know. I am hoping `[dkms][1]` will prevent this in the future. In my case, the modules weren't built when the new kernel was installed, rather, the modules were updated when the kernel was not.

> Dynamic Kernel Module Support (DKMS) is a program/framework that enables generating Linux kernel modules whose sources generally reside outside the kernel source tree. The concept is to have DKMS modules automatically rebuilt when a new kernel is installed.

*Lerhaupt, Gary (September 1, 2003). "Kernel Korner - Exploring Dynamic Kernel Module Support (DKMS)". Linux Journal. Retrieved March 12, 2016.